# Disabling scroll of first item in ListWheelScrollView in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

How to stop scrolling of `ListWheelScrollView` for the first index.

Expected Output : -

`ListWheelScrollView` should stop scrolling when it encounters a disabled item or the first index of ListView. Scroll index should not count the first index, that is it should not move further or to the disabled index.

Expected Output GIF : -

[image]

Code : -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'List',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const List(),
    );
  }
}

class List extends StatefulWidget {
  const List({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ListState createState() => _ListState();
}

class _ListState extends State<List> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("List"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: [
              RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: 1,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 600,
                  width: 800,
                  child: ListWheelScrollView(
                      itemExtent: 100,
                      physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                      onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {},
                      children: [
                        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) ...[
                          Container(
                            color: i != 3 ? Colors.green[200] : Colors.red[200],
                            height: 70,
                            width: 70,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: RotatedBox(
                                quarterTurns: -1,
                                child: Text(i != 3 ? "Enabled" : "Disabled")),
                          )
                        ]
                      ]),
                ),
              ),
              const Positioned(top: 440, child: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_up))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

One solution provided : -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'List',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const ScrollingList(),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollingList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollingList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScrollingListState createState() => _ScrollingListState();
}

class _ScrollingListState extends State<ScrollingList> {
  final controller = FixedExtentScrollController();

  final children = [
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) ScrollingListItem(enabled: i != 0)
  ];

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("List"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: [
              RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: 1,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 600,
                  width: 800,
                  child: ListWheelScrollView(
                    controller: controller,
                    itemExtent: 100,
                    physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                    onSelectedItemChanged: (idx) {
                      if (!children[idx].enabled) {
                        controller.animateToItem(
                          idx + 1,
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                          curve: Curves.linear,
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    children: children,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Positioned(top: 440, child: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_up))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class ScrollingListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool enabled;

  const ScrollingListItem({super.key, required this.enabled});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: enabled ? Colors.green[200] : Colors.red[200],
      height: 70,
      width: 70,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: RotatedBox(
        quarterTurns: -1,
        child: Text(
          enabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It has a bug , the last element(extreme left container) will flash when List Wheel is moved to the disable element : -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is similar to your provided solution but with little changes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'List',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const ScrollingList(),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollingList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollingList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScrollingListState createState() => _ScrollingListState();
}

class _ScrollingListState extends State<ScrollingList> {
  final controller = FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 1);

  final children = [
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) ScrollingListItem(enabled: i != 0)
  ];

  void scrollListener() {
    if (controller.selectedItem == 1) {
      if (controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward) {
        controller.jumpToItem(1);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(scrollListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.removeListener(scrollListener);
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("List"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: [
              RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: 1,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 600,
                  width: 800,
                  child: ListWheelScrollView(
                    controller: controller,
                    itemExtent: 100,
                    physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                    // onSelectedItemChanged: (idx) {
                    //   if (!children[idx].enabled) {
                    //     controller.animateToItem(
                    //       idx + 1,
                    //       duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    //       curve: Curves.linear,
                    //     );
                    //   }
                    // },
                    children: children,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Positioned(top: 440, child: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_up))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class ScrollingListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool enabled;

  const ScrollingListItem({super.key, required this.enabled});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: enabled ? Colors.green[200] : Colors.red[200],
      height: 70,
      width: 70,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: RotatedBox(
        quarterTurns: -1,
        child: Text(
          enabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.
Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You would need a way to detect that the current `index` is disabled to take advantage of the `onSelectedItemChanged` paired with a `FixedExtentScrollController` (don't forget to dispose!) to smoothly go to the center of the item you're scrolling into using `animateToItem()`. You can do this with a class having a enabled/disabled `bool`.

(Also don't name classes the same as dart keywords)

Here's a simple working example.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'List',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const ScrollingList(),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollingList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollingList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScrollingListState createState() => _ScrollingListState();
}

class _ScrollingListState extends State<ScrollingList> {
  final controller = FixedExtentScrollController();

  final children = [
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) ScrollingListItem(enabled: i != 3)
  ];

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("List"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: [
              RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: 1,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 600,
                  width: 800,
                  child: ListWheelScrollView(
                    controller: controller,
                    itemExtent: 100,
                    physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                    onSelectedItemChanged: (idx) {
                      if (!children[idx].enabled) {
                        controller.animateToItem(
                          idx,
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                          curve: Curves.linear,
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    children: children,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Positioned(top: 440, child: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_up))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class ScrollingListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool enabled;

  const ScrollingListItem({super.key, required this.enabled});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: enabled ? Colors.green[200] : Colors.red[200],
      height: 70,
      width: 70,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: RotatedBox(
        quarterTurns: -1,
        child: Text(
          enabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this before, but the onSelectedItemChanged() method only works when moved to an item, making the last item flash when ListView is moved to the disabled Item(if the first index is set as disabled).

Comment: @Ramji did you try testing my code snippet without changing it? It's working exactly as you asked. Whether you want to hold and drag or swipe, it will animate to the disabled item and stop on it (and stops the dragging).

Comment: And if you want to stop before/after the disabled index, then just check -/+1 the current `idx`, such as `if (!children[idx + 1].enabled)`  (obviously checking if you're in bounds of the list)

Comment: yes, that's what I did but if we set the disabled item at the 0th index then when we drag or swipe to the 0th index the last item will flash, it appears and then disappears quickly

Comment: @Ramji I'm not seeing this with children length being 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 50. Testing on iPhone 14 Pro. Maybe you're seeing a platform specific bug which would then be another SO question

Comment: I have added a gif in my question which shows the bug which I am talking about also I did a test on multiple different mobile device, and every device gave that output